# Python object isn't being garbage collected, but isn't referenced and isn't uncollectable

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

There is a class in my application which, after instantiation, is never garbage collected. How could this be?

So far I've ruled out:

- References to the object (ex, caches; see test below which takes a snapshot of all live objects then tries to find a back reference from the leaking objects to any object in that snapshot)
- Uncollectable object cycles (`gc.garbage` is empty and there *shouldn't* be anything with a `__del__` in the graph; see test below)
- Forcing a collection (see test below; `gc.collect()` is called until it returns `0`)
- Django / Django model specific things (I've tested other models and they don't leak like this one does)
- C extensions or other low-level trickery (as far as I know, NumPy and Pandas are the only extensions which touch this object graph)

The class in question is one of the core business logic models in the application, and there *are* a large number of reference cycles within instances (the `recalculate()` method creates a cyclic graph with ~hundreds of nodes), but this *should* be straightforward for the garbage collector to collect.

So! What am I missing? How could unreferenced instances of this class be staying alive?

**Update**: The refcount from `sys.getrefcount(…) = 16` is larger than  `len(gc.get_referrers(…)) = 15`, so there must be a ref outside of `gc` land (thanks for the suggestion, [Thomas Wouters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17624/thomas-wouters))

Test case which reveals the leak:

```
import gc
import weakref
import objgraph
from myapp import BusinessClass

def find_live_objects(cls):
    """ Returns all live objects of type ``cls``. """
    return [
        weakref.ref(o)
        for o in gc.get_objects()
        if type(o) == cls
    ]

def test():
    # Load and delete a similar object in case there are
    # and class-specific caches hiding somewhere.
    # Note: the results are the same without this.
    a = BusinessClass.objects.get(id=1)
    a.recalculate()
    del a

    # Snapshot all live objects
    live_now = list(gc.get_objects())
    live_set = set(id(x) for x in live_now)
    print "Live objects:", len(live_set)

    # Create and delete the object we're interested in
    a = BusinessClass.objects.get(id=2)
    a.recalculate()
    del a

    print "gc:", gc.collect()
    print "gc:", gc.collect()
    print "gc:", gc.collect()
    print "Garbage:", gc.garbage

    live_list = find_live_objects(BusinessClass)
    print "Found:", [x() for x in live_list]

    live = live_list[1]
    print "Searching for:", live()

    chain = objgraph.find_backref_chain(
        live(),
        (lambda x: id(x) in live_set),
        max_depth=999999,
    )
    print "Chain:", chain

test()
```

And when run:

```
$ python find-leaks.py
Live objects: 132062
gc: 21
gc: 0
gc: 0
Garbage: []
Found: [BusinessClass(id=1), BusinessClass(id=2)]
Searching for: BusinessClass(id=2)
Chain: [BusinessClass(2)]
```

Note that no backrefs to any of the live objects are found.

Version info:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 6, 11, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: What happens in the `objects.get` method? It would be really nice to see a smaller example with that method defined. Do you have circular referencing for the objects (id=1 -> id=2)?

Comment: My initial thought is the manual deletion of `a`.. is that just in your test code? Since Django querysets are done lazily I'm wondering if its possible that they are holding a reference somewhere

Comment: @zeroth there's no relationship between the two objects (1 and 2). I'm loading the first one to make sure that any object-specific caches are warmed up, but the results are the same without it. I've added a note now. The only circular references are within the object graph itself.

Comment: @Sayse I was seeing this issue in production, so it's unlikely to be an issue with the manual deletion. I've tested other Django models and none of them have issues, so I don't *think* it's a QuerySet-related thing.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was more for part of your test, also the queryset seems to be the only django specific thing in your code. If at all possible you may want to try just making a normal object and seeing if that still is the same to reduce your bugs scope. Is the graph using any third party tool? What version of python/django/et al?

Comment: Ohh I'm glad you asked! I tested this with a few more straightforward graphs and cycles (just throwing a few hundred nodes together) and I saw the expected result (ie, the first call to `gc.collect()` returned a large number and all of the nodes were collected). I've added Python, Django, etc versions. And the only significant 3rd party libraries used in this code path are NumPy and Pandas (the app as a whole uses a bunch, but they aren't called here).

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I don't know enough about Pandas to know what limits it can handle and how it does so, Obviously django 1.6 support ended in [april](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) so I don't know of the django team have found a solution to this in newer versions for you (but I'd imagine this isn't a viable solution anywho). I'm afraid I can't be of much more help but I'd definitely try to make a simple test class that can perform `recalculate` without the need to touch anything django-ey

Comment: It's a little hard to suggest anything without an actual reproducible example, but I don't think your use of objgraph.find_backref_chain is going to show much (you're asking for a chain from a BusinessClass instance to your BusinessClass instance). Probably more interesting would be looking at sys.getrefcount() of the instance: before you 'del a', after you 'del a' (through the weakref), after you gc.collect(), etc. Also, gc.get_referrers().

Comment: Ah, I misread your find_backref_chain code (live_set and live_list, really? :) Even so, the objgraph module uses the gc module, and the gc module only knows about objects that participate in cyclic-gc. It will not find references from objects that do not participate in gc. It seems obvious something that doesn't participate in gc is holding a reference to your instance (but looking at sys.getrefcount would indicate that, too.)

Comment: What sort of things would there be which don't participate in gc? Also, you might be on to something with `sys.getrefcount()`: it shows 16, while `len(gc.get_referrers(…))` is 15! Now, to figure out where that errant reference is coming from…

Comment: It's just C types that might not participate in GC; any C type that does not define tp_traverse. There's also the separate consideration of being a GC root. If an object stores references to Python objects but does not implement tp_traverse, those references won't be found. If the object *does* implement tp_traverse but it is not referenced (directly or through objects implementing tp_traverse) by any GC roots, its references also won't be found (since the object itself won't be found.) Of course, it may also just be a refcount bug somewhere. "gdb" might well be the easiest way to find out.